Using scala Dynamic to pass a dynamic argument list
I would like to define a function that can be passed a dynamic argument list. Something like this:
  def foo(fields: (String, Any)*) = ???

In such a way that I could call it using dynamically named arguments. Something like :
  foo(arg1 -> "1", arg2 = 2)

Where arg1 and arg2 can be anything. Is there a way I can achieve something like this using the scala Dynamic object?

Why not just Map[String, Any]?  or with (String, Any)* it works if you use quotes: foo("arg1" -> "1", "arg2" -> 2) - BTW, what is the meta-problem you are trying to solve here?

You may also check into Shapeless Record either for inspiration or to use it directly: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.chuusai/shapeless_2.13/2.3.10/shapeless/record$.html#Record

I achieved a solution by mimicking the approach used in the ScalaJS library for their js.Dynamic.literal objects. So my complete solutions is:
case class Params(fields: Map[String, Double]) extends Dynamic

object Params {
  def apply(fields: (String, Any)*): Params = Params(fields.toMap.mapValues {
    case d: Double => d
    case f: Float => f.toDouble
    case l: Long => l.toDouble
    case i: Int => i.toDouble
    case o =>
      throw new RuntimeException("Invalid parameter value: " + o)
  })
}

object params extends scala.Dynamic {
  def applyDynamicNamed(name: String)(fields: (String, Any)*): Params = Params(fields: _*)
  def applyDynamic(name: String)(fields: (String, Any)*): Params = Params(fields: _*)
}

Which can then be used thus:
params(a = 1, b = 2.4, c = 0)

